# DRF response doesn't have json method but it's used

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a situation that I don't understand, if I do something like that in my tests, returning this object:

```
response = Response()
response.status_code = 200
response.data = json.dumps({'bla': 'test_bla'})
```

I can check it and:

```
response.data # works
response.json() # doesn't
```

I see [the doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/) and I don't see it has the method 'json'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this, you can use the `response.json()`

```
import requests

response = requests.models.Response()
response.status_code = 200
response._content = (json.dumps(content)).encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

`rest_framework.Response` (which does not have a `json()` method) and  `urllib3.HTTPResponse` (which does have a `json()` method) are not the same response object :

- `rest_framework.Response` is used to build a response on your views.
- `urllib3.HTTPResponse` is used when an HTTP query is performed.

`urllib3.HTTPResponse` is also often found on unit tests (through DRF `APIClient`) or remote HTTP queries, that's may be why you can see it on some examples. It might be the reason why you might think that `rest_framework.Response` should have a `json()` method but does not.

Comment: Good point, I'll check better both, but It still doesn't work `AttributeError: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'json'`